# Make some process/work during ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, browser

I have one html page with `PHP(Apache web server)` business logic,

In that When I click on **generate pdf button** one **pdf is generated** with help of ajax call

But my pdf is so large so It take time meanwhile when I am clicking on any other website link than it does not open the web page till the ajax request got completed

Any idea to solve it means User can able to browse other website pages during the execution of ajax call

Thanks.

Comment: Show us the code, you may just need to set it to be synchronous

Comment: Setting it to synchronous will also block the browser don't you think?

Comment: They could do it using HTML5 worker threads

Comment: @LemuelBotha any best suggested link for HTML5 worker threads

Comment: Here is a pretty informative one: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp - then you just need to adapt how webworkers work to call your pdfgenerating function and you should be able to achieve your goal

Answer (score 3):

Yes Both Synchronous and asynchronous AJAX call Blocking or queuing the subsequent HTTP requests until the AJAX request got completed.